# Visual Studio Macros Editor

Tags: vba, ide, ms-office

Is there a way to change the macro editor from this default one:

[image: screenshot]

It feels like such a downgrade from Visual Studio 2010. Can I configure Office to use that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no there is no way to my knowledge, VS.NET does not support VBA.

what you can do if you are creating a new word or excel file is create a managed office solution, having installed the VSTO 2010 (Visual Studio Tools for Office) you are able to create managed documents which are handled inside VS 2010 and the automation language is not VBA anymore but C# or VB.NET instead.

this is a viable solution for new files, for legacy files either you convert them if they are small or you keep old VBA code and old VBA editor as in your picture.

Mark I wish MS made a tool to convert from the old format to the new one! :(

Comment: So you mean like office add-in projects in VS?

Comment: yes, this is how they are called now, in the past they were called managed document projects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430 MS changes the names all the times. Could be that you have to install an additional component called VSTO 2010 to have the project template visible in New project wizard in VS 2010

Comment: Yeah made a few in C#, I prefer that to VB, but can you make one that only applies to one document like a macro-enabled document and add controls *in* the document?

Answer (score 0):

There are things you can do to improve it:

1. Tools > Options > Editor :
   Uncheck "Auto Syntax Check"
2. Tools > Options > Edit Format:
   Customize the colors and font
3. Install the VBA Rubberduck:
   http://rubberduckvba.com/

The RubberDuck does auto-indent for you. It also helps you with "unit testing, source control, from code inspections, and refactorings"